# Maven 2 Weblogic.xml replacement

Tags: maven-2, weblogic, classpath, war, directory-structure

I am having a problem about placing weblogic.xml under WEB-INF folder after mvn install. My weblogic.xml file is under src/main/resources/weblogic.xml and I want it to be placed under WEB-INF after install.(packaging is "war" by the way)

I tried this:

```
<resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <targetPath>../resources</targetPath>
                <excludes><exclude>web.xml</exclude><exclude>weblogic.xml</exclude></excludes>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources/config</directory>
                <targetPath>..</targetPath>
                <includes><include>weblogic.xml</include></includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
```

It is working with install but when I want a classpath using eclipse:eclipse, It gives the error :

> *Description  Resource    Path    Location    Type Cannot nest output folder 'ResponseManager/target/WEB-INF/resources' inside output folder
>   'ResponseManager/target/WEB-INF'  ResponseManager     Build path  Build
>   Path Problem*

because of this conf in classpath:

```
  <classpathentry kind="src" path="src/main/resources" output="target/WEB-INF/resources" excluding="web.xml|weblogic.xml|**/*.java"/>
  <classpathentry kind="src" path="src/main/resources/config" output="target/WEB-INF" including="weblogic.xml" excluding="**/*.java"/>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Normally files under `src/main/resources` get packaged along the compiled class files, in a webapp they would be placed in `WEB-INF/classes`. Is there any reason why you can't put these under the standard path `src/main/webapp`?

If you need to package additional files which are not in the `src/main/webapp` folder then it would be better to configure these resources in the war plugin like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <webResources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/config</directory>
                <targetPath>WEB-INF</targetPath>
                <includes>
                    <include>weblogic.xml</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </webResources>                    
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

It should be possible to specify the `targetPath` as above but I think it would be cleaner to reproduce the wanted directory structure inside your source folder.

Comment: I just do not want them to be placed under classes folder because they are resources, not classes. This is one thing which I do not agree with Maven: the folder structure. Thanks, it worked